# error LNK2005 and error LNK2019 in C/C++ mix program

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, winapi

A program have:  raw_mouse.h,  raw_mouse.c  RawInputRegistry.h  RawInputRegistry.cpp and main.cpp

In the raw_mouse.h,

I defined:

```
typedef WINUSERAPI INT (WINAPI *pGetRawInputDeviceList)(OUT PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST pRawInputDeviceList, IN OUT PINT puiNumDevices, IN UINT cbSize);

void testme();
```

In the raw_mouse.c I have:

```
_RRID = (pRegisterRawInputDevices)GetProcAddress(user32,"RegisterRawInputDevices");

void testme()
{
    int a =10;
}
```

I included raw_mouse.h in the raw_mouse.c and also included raw_mouse.h in the RawInputRegistry.h, finally include RawInputRegistry.h in the main.cpp

However, I got these errors:

```
RawInputRegistry.obj : error LNK2005: "int (__stdcall* _GRID)(struct HRAWINPUT__ *,unsigned int,void *,int *,unsigned int)" (?_GRID@@3P6GHPAUHRAWINPUT__@@IPAXPAHI@ZA) already defined in main.obj

RawInputRegistry.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl testme(void)" (?testme@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "protected: __thiscall RawInputEventRegistry::RawInputEventRegistry(void)" (??0RawInputEventRegistry@@IAE@XZ)
```

Not sure if I should use extern "C" to embrace all the code in raw_mouse.c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not sure if I *should* use extern "C" to embrace all the code in raw_mouse.c?

You **have** to put s.th. like the following into your `raw_mouse.h` file to make it [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [c](/questions/tagged/c) `#include` compliant simultaneously:

```
#ifndef RAW_MOUSE_H__
#define RAW_MOUSE_H__

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Your C function declarations go here ... */

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif /* RAW_MOUSE_H__ */
```

Comment: I think most of the problems have been solved after adding your code. However, the first error seems still there:RawInputRegistry.obj : error LNK2005: __GRID already defined in main.obj

Comment: @lightrek Don't know specifically for VS2010, but there's usually some linker option to allow multiple symbol definitions (to override weak symbols from linked libraries). Other possibility is you **really** have an unwanted multiple definition. Sorry, I can't tell what `?_GRID@@3P6GHPAUHRAWINPUT__@@IPAXPAHI@ZA` is from the code you're showing in your question.

Comment: After moving    `typedef WINUSERAPI INT (WINAPI *pGetRawInputDeviceList)(OUT PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST pRawInputDeviceList, IN OUT PINT puiNumDevices, IN UINT cbSize);` from raw_mouse.h to raw_mouse.c the error was gone. But still do not know why this happens?

Comment: @lightrek The reason is some stupid M$ compiler **preprocessing crap** most probably ...